# Embedded video keeps playing when going to next page

Tags: html, vimeo, embedded-video

I am embedding a Vimeo video onto a survey (Alchemer). If the video has not finished (or been paused), and I click to the next page, the video from that previous page continues in the background until it is finished playing, even though it is not on the page.

I am using the embed code from Vimeo - I have an embed code for both responsive and fixed. What do I need to add to the below two codes to ensure that the video stops playing when moving to the next page, regardless of whether the video has been paused or finished playing.

Responsive embed code:

```
<div style="padding:56.25% 0 0 0;position:relative;"><iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/581420395?badge=0&amp;autopause=0&amp;player_id=0&amp;app_id=58479" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; fullscreen; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%;" title="Neck Flexion Test"></iframe></div><script src="https://player.vimeo.com/api/player.js"></script>
```

Fixed embed code:

```
<iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/581420395?badge=0&amp;autopause=0&amp;player_id=0&amp;app_id=58479" width="1920" height="1080" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; fullscreen; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen title="Neck Flexion Test"></iframe>
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that you *"move to the next page"*? Is that possible you use some sort of steps showing and hiding divs?

Comment: I think the issue is, the questions are all on the same page, however they are viewed 'one at a time', so to the user they are separate pages, however behind the scenes they are one page.

Would there still be a way to have the video pause / stop when clicking 'next', using the Alchemer survey software?